# Need to update my Python version to 2.7 in my lxc container

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos7, python-2.6, lxc

I couldn't remove 2.6 Python which is already installed

Because if I remove then the system is breaking down.

If I install 2.7 and tried to see python version in the base (rpm -q --provides python | grep abi)

python(abi) = 2.6
python-abi = 2.6

I tried to reinstall the epel-release. Still no luck. (epel release 6.8)
Tried to see my system is upto date. All good.

What I can do to change it to 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are actually on centos 6 and not centos 7 since centos 7 comes with python 2.7.6.  In any case, if you want python 2.7 on centos 6, the recommended way is to build it from source and then install it using `altinstall` so that python 2.7 can run alongside python 2.6.  You can also install python 2.7 using [the IUS repository](https://ius.io/GettingStarted/) and then installing using `yum -y install python27`.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes Correct. Did a mistake while I installed my container. Thank you. As am new to lxcs and novice to linux, I make such mistakes. I assure I am learning from this as well.